# Windows 8.1 app Navigation - Page failing to load

Tags: c#, windows

My app has multiple pages.  I start with a main page.  Buttons are used to navigate pages and back.  I do not use the back button at all.  I have one page that works perfectly and I can go back and forth from the main page to that page.  However, I am having an issue with another page.  I can use the button to navigate to this second page and another button to go back to the main page.  When I go to navigate back to the second page again using the same button as the first time, I get an error saying the page failed to load.  I can't seem to figure this out. I set it up exactly like the first page, but for some reason it won't allow me to load the second page multiple times.

I am using the following code to navigate:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(page_name));
```